# Combining two arrays into one javascript json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have two arrays:

```
var itemname = [ "t-shirt", "trouser", "vest" ];
var itemqty = [ "3", "5", "2" ];
```

I want to combine them into:

```
var keyval = [{
    itemname: "trouser", 
    itemqty: 5
}, {
    itemname: "vest, 
    itemqty: 2
},{
    itemname: "t-shirt", 
    itemqty: 3
}]
```

How can I achieve this using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service and there are hundreds of similar issues you could search for on this site. If you tried something and it isn't working then you should be posting that code and asking for specific help with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keyVal = [];
for (var i = 0; i < itemname.length; i++)
{
    keyVal.push({ itemname: itemname[i], itemqty: itemqty[i] });
}
```